# Change the mouse scroll sensitivity in KDE Plasma?

Tags: kde, mouse, plasma, x

I have a Logitech M325 mouse and use KDE Plasma 5 on X11.  I am a long-time middle-button paster.  I love the newer hi-res wheels for actually scrolling things, especially given that I can just put a spin on it

However, I've found it difficult to paste because pressing the wheel often results in a bit of scroll too.  I most often notice this in konsole where I'm pasting to bash and suddenly find myself in older shell history rather than appending to the command I was building.

Anyone know of a neat trick to make the first few scroll ticks be ignored or achieve something similar?

Comment: I avoid non-notched "smooth" scroll wheels for exactly that reason. Have one at work and it just keeps scrolling when I don't want to, and that's even on Windows with the official drivers.

Comment: @zak The M325 has a notched wheel, but it's subtle and insufficient without exerting care.  If the notch was more pronounced, that would adversely affect the spin quality.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll wheel sensitivity setting is not available on X11 when using libinput, as the driver does not expose the setting.

See: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452045#c3

There is currently a merge request open for this in
the xf86-input-libinput repository at X.org's gitlab.freektop.org instance:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-libinput/-/merge_requests/12

The patch has not been merged, but a kind soul, evandrocoan, left instructions for building the patch on a Debian-based system. If you're comfortable making some code edits and building the source code, you can use these instructions to make the changes you're looking for. I've made some edits to the instructions for clarity:

> @tbodt Thank you very much for this patch! I was just able to install
> this and it was wonderful. For the first time I could have good scroll
> (without having to use bugged hacks as imwheel). For anyone
> interested, my steps to run this where:
>
> 1. First check which version of xserver-xorg-input-libinput is available
>    for my system:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
> dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-input-libinput
> ```
>
> The output will provide a version similar to this:
>
> ```
>  ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput                   0.29.0-1                              amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
> ```
>
> 2. I checkout on the
>    git tag 0.29.0 because my system has version 0.29.0 on the package
>    manager.
> 3. I applied the patch:
>
> ```c
> --- a/src/xf86libinput.c
> +++ b/src/xf86libinput.c @@ -1651,6 +1651,7 
> @@ calculate_axis_value(struct xf86libinput *driver_data,
>         value = libinput_event_pointer_get_axis_value(event, axis);
>     }  
> +   value *= 3; // This triples the sensitivity
>     *value_out = value;
>  
>     return true;
> ```
>
> 4. And installed it:
>
> ```sh
> sudo apt-get build-dep libinput 
> autoreconf -vif 
> ./configure --prefix=/usr 
> make 
> make install
> ```
>
> 5. Logout and login of your xorg session reload the changes.

See the rest of the comments for more information and other possible changes.